# Use background image in css along with white color background in center of page

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I am using this code to use an image as background inside `<body>` tag

```
body {
   margin: 0; auto;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   background-image: url('image-blur.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   opacity:1;
}
```

But the image overlays the white background of the page. I would like the image to overlay only on the left side and right side of the html page. In the center of the page data exists. I need to maintain the white color background on data area but at the same time use as a fixed background the image. How can i achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/nakata/pen/LQddvz

Comment: Yes exactly like this

Comment: ok i'll that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation of that layout:
Note: All the colors, dimensions and images are just for demonstrations purposes. Tweak them to your needs.

https://codepen.io/nakata/pen/LQddvz

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">Stuff</div>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/200?image=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use multiple background:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to right,transparent 20%, white 20%, white 80%,transparent 0)
  ,url('https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/');
  min-height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: It shows me one image left but the other is still left oriented and i want to be right oriented.

Comment: Specifically The white area where data exists should be bigger. Can't make it bigger because from one side the image is oriented over the data in the middle of the page!

Comment: @stefanosn am not getting you :) can you elaborate ?  it's a very simplified example that can be adjusted ;)